# Текст накладывается при небольших разрешениях

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Заметил, что если зайти на сайт с мобильных устройств, то текст накладывается сам на себя. Как можно избавиться?
[image: Пример]

Код стандартный:
`<h4 class="classic-title text-center"><span> Текст </span></h4>`

CSS:

```
.classic-title 
{ 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  padding-bottom: 8px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
  font-weight: 300; 
} 

.classic-title span 
{ 
  padding-bottom: 8px; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid; 
  font-weight: 400; 
} 

h4 { 
  font-size: 16px; 
  line-height: 22px; 
}
```

Comment: Привидите ваш css код класса classic-title а так же тега h4 (результирующий).

Comment: может быть вам не border-bottom использовать а text-decoration: underline?

Comment: кстати работает хорошо при `.classic-title span { padding-bottom: 3px;` при уменьшении нижнего внутреннего отступа.

Comment: действительно, уменьшение значения padding-bottom решило проблему, спасибо!)